# apache redirect/rewrite http to https with many virtualhosts

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have an apache webserver that has about 150 VirtualHosts spread out over 9 IP addresses. I'd like to redirect or rewrite http connections to https. The solutions I've found have the rewrite/redirect inside the  definitions but since this server has so many, I was hoping there was a more elegant way of doing it other than adding 150 rewrites.

Its ubuntu 22 btw.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a redirect to https with the %{http_host} variable. Just bind to port 80 and redirect everything to https. No need to know what the hostname is.

Untested but this should work :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location "/">
    Redirect "https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

[almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289269/using-redirectmatch-with-http-host-in-the-destination?noredirect=1&lq=1)